# How to use attribute name stored in variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method.

```
def method_name(object, field_name_1, field_name_2)
  var = SomeClass.new(:field => object.field_name_1, :field => object.field_name_2)
  object.update_attributes(:"#{field_name_1}" => var)
end
```

When I try to access object.field_name_1 this way it is impossible because it searches for field_name_1 not it's value (that is field name). Is there anyway I can use value of field_name_1 as name of field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object.read_attribute(field_name_1.to_sym)
object.update_attributes(field_name_1.to_sym => var)
```

This should work, but i am not sure of what you are trying to do.